# Is there a more natural/casual synonym for "Implemented" that does not imply progression?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Summary**

The right word would be a close synonym for Implemented and make sense on its own as a status description in tables and filters, but more natural sounding in this context and without the implication of progression that Completed has. I could maybe work with a two-word phrase but would much prefer a single word.

"The changes to the shift were ___ after the request was accepted and approved"

or

"The request was ___ after it was accepted and approved"

**Context**

- Users of my software can request to trade a shift with another user. This trade is subject to both being Accepted by the other user and Approved by their supervisor (which can happen in any order), and could be rejected by either.
- Users can also receive requests from higher-ups for modifications to a scheduled shift, which the user can accept or reject.

Either type of request can be described as "Rejected" if it did not go through, but I'm looking for a single word to describe the ones that *did* go through. I can't use Approved or Accepted, as in the case of trades those are separate statuses that need to both be true before the trade can take place.

Implemented captures the meaning I'm looking for, but sounds kind of odd and clunky in this context. I *swear* there's a better word on the tip of my tongue that I can't seem to find by searching synonyms, but it's entirely possible that my brain can't remember it because it doesn't actually exist.

I'm currently using Completed as it sounds more natural, however it's not a perfect fit because it implies work done over a timeline with a start and end, and these changes are made immediately as soon as the program knows it should do them.

Other rejected synonyms: Executed, effected, carried out, applied, enacted, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actioned**

> action verb [ T usually passive ] UK  /ˈæk.ʃən/ US  /ˈæk.ʃən/   to do
> something to deal with a particular problem or matter: I'll just run
> through the minutes of the last meeting, raising those points that
> still have to be actioned.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/actioned

Comment: I think this word fits what I was asking for best. Still doesn't feel 100% right but at this point I'm convinced English just doesn't have a word that would.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following choices, although there may be others:

> The changes to the shift were **made** after the request was accepted and approved.

Or, better yet, strengthen it by saying...

> Shift schedules were **changed** after the request was accepted and approved.

Answer (score 0):

> The changes to the shift were effectuated after the request was
> accepted and approved.
>
> The request was effectuated after it was accepted and approved.

In light of the OP's rejected verbs and the comment:

> ...these changes are made immediately as soon as the program knows it
> should do them.

I suggest this synonym of the verb *effect*.

*Effectuate* is formal word, but it pinpoints the action the OP refers to, and it logically follows acceptance and approval.  Like *to bring about*, it emphasizes the *start/cause* of something rather than its progress or completion.

> ...these changes are made immediately as soon as the program knows it
> should do them.

> **effectuate** (v.)
>
> To cause or bring about (something) : to put (something) into effect
> or operation [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effectuated)

---

> Section 23 of the Utilities Act requires any public service company
> desiring to make any change in its schedule of rates to **effectuate**
> such change by filing with this Commission.... [*Annual Report of the
> Public Utilities Commission, State of Maine*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Annual_Report_of_the_Public_Utilities_Co/KVVIAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=effectuate%20a%20change%20schedule&pg=PA35&printsec=frontcover)

> To **effectuate** this change in policy, as well as to respond to petition
> to EPA from both environmental and industry groups seeking an
> accelerated schedule, ... [Hunton & Williams; *Clean Air
> Handbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Clean_Air_Handbook/TCMJBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22To%20effectuate%20this%20change%22)

Comment: Why use *effectuate* when *effect* means the exact same thing — with less fuss?

Comment: In part the confusion about *affect/effect*, but mainly because the OP rejected it.

Answer (score 0):

After a shift reassignment request is both *approved* and *accepted* by all parties involved, I would imagine that it advances to ***reassigned***.

In the sense that your application has done its job in reassigning, its job has been completed and is now complete.

But the shift still needs to be completed. I think that is where your struggle lies.

Save *completed* for completed shifts, if your app tracks that.

Answer (score 0):

Would any of the following suffice?

- Resolved
- Confirmed
- Fixed
- Set
- Recorded

As a fellow developer, I tend to go with Completed, but I can see your dilemma here.